# Keeping vertical swiping scrolling the page in horizontal flickable slider

Tags: android, web-applications, mobile, touch, zepto

In my mobile webapp I have a `flickable imageslider` which allows you to swipe through the items `horizontally`, using `flickable.js` (http://blog.kojo.com.au/flickable-zepto-plugin/)

Something like [this](http://blog.kojo.com.au/demos/flickable/demo2.html)

This promo takes up a quite significant space on a mobile device. Right now on android devices, if I try to scroll vertically ON the space of the imageslider, the page wont scroll. This is quite bad for the user experience. This does not seem to be a problem on iOS devices.

I have tried to fetch the touch event and check if it's a vertical swipe, but I don't know where to go from there.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a config object to flickable to tell him not to prevent the default touch behavior (page scrolling).

Example:

$('#news ul').flickable({
                    section: 'li',
                    preventDefault: false
                });

Comment: This completely breaks the functionality for me. the vertical swiping breaks.